# Which WMI class corresponds to ASP.Net Apps v1.14322?

Tags: asp.net, windows, wmi

How can I determine which classes correspond to which counters? I'm able to pull up all of the classes but have no way of associating them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...I realize on some servers the WMI classes are incorrect. On this server I was able to determine the correct class.